# git log --format=format Difference between common commit and merge commit

Tags: git, merge, format, git-log

How to distinguish common commit and merge commit in:

```
git log --format=format:"something"
```

It can distinguish recursive merge from any other because recursive has two parents, and I can use %p option and parse it, but what if I have common commit and fast forwarding merge commit?

Is it possible?

Comment: I've just come to this. Actually, it is not possible, because fast-forwarding doesn't appeared in git log. Thanks.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean. What is a "common" commit, and what is a "fast forwarding merge commit"? Merge commits have at least 2 parents, while non-merge commits have only 1. Fast-forward merging never creates a new merge commit. So a "fast forward merge commit" makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't distinguish fast-forward merge, because of fast-forward merge doesn't create a commit.
It just moves branch pointer (see picture):

[image]

Comment: This answer isn't completely correct. `--commit` doesn't force a fast-forward merge to make a merge commit...you can't force fast-forward merges to make merge commits, by definition. What you really want to say is `--no-ff`, as in "no fast-forward merge"... ***that*** creates a merge commit.